# Make an almost quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

I wanted to fool a friend by giving him a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) that *almost* worked, but became sloppier and sloppier.

Create a program that, when run, will output the program, but one character off. Either one character can be added, removed or both (one character changes). But only **one** character.

Your score will be `(length of your program) / floor(sqrt(number of times the program almost quines))` (Where `/ 0` is infinity)

`number of times the program almost quines` is how many times your program runs while only changing one character in stdout. Your program may not accept input. It may also not print a program it has already printed.

You may also **not** add a character that you have previously added before, or remove a character from the same index. For example, if you have added `1` before, and you add `1` again, that's where the `number of times the program almost quines` stops. If you remove the first character, you may not remove the first character again. If you changed the third character into a `2`, you may not add a `2` or remove the third character.

Comment: whats a quine ?

Comment: @Agawa001 A [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) is a program that prints itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## CJam, 0.000884

```
{_,6/[{64md}6*](124+\+'�f++`"1$~"}""1$~
```

Here, � denotes the unprintable character with code point 128. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B_%2C6%2F%5B%7B64md%7D6*%5D(124%2B%5C%2B'%C2%80f%2B%2B%60%221%24~%22%7D%22%221%24~)

#### Idea

This approach appends all UCS characters (original specification) with code points between U+4000000 and U+7FFFFFFF to the initially empty string that follows the code block.

We choose [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), which encodes each of these characters using a 6 byte string as follows:

```
1111110u₂     10vvvvvv₂     10wwwwww₂     10xxxxxx₂     10yyyyyy₂     10zzzzzz₂

252 + u       128 + vvvvvv  128 + wwwwww  128 + xxxxxx  128 + yyyyyy  128 + zzzzzz
```

Thus, we can encode the *nth* character in this range by computing its 6 least significant digits in base 64 and adding 252 to the most significant and 128 to the remaining ones.

#### Scoring

There are `2 ** 31 = 2,147,483,648` 6 byte UTF-8 characters and the length of the original code is 39, so the score is `39 / floor(2 ** 15.5) = 39 / 46340 = 0.0008416055243849806`.

#### How it works

```
{                                }""    e# Push the code block and an empty string.
                                    1$~ e# Execute a copy of the code block.
 _,                                     e# Push the length of the string.
   6/                                   e# Divide by 6 to get the number of chars.
      {64md}6*                          e# Perform modular division six times.
     [        ]                         e# Collect the results in an array.
               (124+\+                  e# Add 124 to the first element.
                      '�f+              e# Add 128 to all and cast each to Char.
                          +             e# Concatenate the strings.
                           `            e# Push a string representation.
                            "1$~"       e# Push '1$~' to complete the quine.
```

Comment: I am accepting this because of your _first_ (lower) score. I will allow it.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 46 bytes, 65504 add, 65505 del, Score 0.127424

```
{`-2<_0c#)!{'#/~(_)\+\+S+]'#*}*W<"
}_~"e# 
}_~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%60-2%3C_0c%23)!%7B'%23%2F~(_)%5C%2B%5C%2BS%2B%5D'%23*%7D*W%3C%22%0A%7D_~%22e%23%20%0A%7D_~)

The basic form is a standard generalised CJam quine. To "almost quine", there's a comment `e#` at the end of the quine's block, where I can freely add characters without affecting the code. Note that the comment initially contains a single space.

The program continues adding characters to the *front* of the comment, starting at `!` and then going in order of ASCII value. CJam's character codes wrap around after 2<sup>16</sup> so at some point, this will add a null byte. Once that happens, the program starts removing bytes from the *end* of the comment (such that the position of the removed character is always different) until the comment is empty.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 19 bytes, 65536 add, 0 del, Score 0.074219

```
"a"{\)_)++`\"_~"}_~
```

Simpler is better.